# Suppress ORA-01403: no data found excpetion

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following code

```
SELECT SUM(nvl(book_value,
                   0))
    INTO v_balance
    FROM account_details
    WHERE currency = 'UGX';

--Write the balance away

SELECT SUM(nvl(book_value,
                   0))
    INTO v_balance
    FROM account_details
    WHERE currency = 'USD';

--Write the balance away
```

Now the problem is, there might not be data in the table for that specific currency, but there might be data for the 'USD' currency. So basically I want to select the sum into my variable and if there is no data I want my stored proc to continue and not throw the 01403 exception.

I don't want to put every select into statement in a BEGIN EXCEPTION END block either, so is there some way I can suppress the exception and just leave the v_balance variable in an undefined (NULL) state without the need for exception blocks?

Comment: The SUM aggregate function does not throw an exception if there are no matches, it just returns null. Your code should already do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select nvl(balance,0) 
into v_balance
from 
(
    select sum(nvl(book_value,0)) as balance
    from account_details
    where currency = 'UGX'
);
```

Comment: Your statement is equivalent to select nvl(sum(book_value),0) into v_balance
    from account_details
    where currency = 'UGX'

Comment: Correct and much simpler than an inner select :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT L1.PKCODE L1CD,  L1.NAME L1N, L1.LVL L1LVL,
          L2.PKCODE L2CD, L2.NAME L2N,  L2.LVL L2LVL,
          L5.PKCODE L5CD, L5.NAME L5N,

INFOTBLM.OPBAL (  L5.PKCODE, :PSTDT, :PSTUC, :PENUC, :PSTVT, :PENVT ) OPBAL,
INFOTBLM.DEBIT    ( L5.PKCODE, :PSTDT,:PENDT, :PSTUC, :PENUC, :PSTVT, :PENVT ) AMNTDR,
INFOTBLM.CREDIT ( L5.PKCODE, :PSTDT,:PENDT, :PSTUC, :PENUC, :PSTVT, :PENVT ) AMNTCR

FROM   FSLVL  L1, FSLVL L2,  FSMAST L5

WHERE  L2.FKCODE  =  L1.PKCODE
AND        L5.FKCODE  =  L2.PKCODE

AND        L5.PKCODE Between :PSTCD AND NVL(:PENCD,:PSTCD)

GROUP BY  L1.PKCODE ,  L1.NAME , L1.LVL ,
                 L2.PKCODE , L2.NAME ,  L2.LVL ,
                 L5.PKCODE , L5.NAME 

ORDER BY L1.PKCODE, L2.PKCODE,  L5.PKCODE
```

Comment: Could you add any explanation to it, that others could reproduce your atempt to solve the problem, if they get on this question because they encoutnered a smiliar problem?